# How can i create a new file and put some user defined integers(Using Scanner class) and then read it?

Tags: java, oop, filereader

I want to write a program which creates a new file and put some user input integers in it and then reads it from a file within the same class.

I have successfully created a file and put some user input in it but the problem occurs while I try to read the file whatever I do it just keeps giving me different errors, I am just curious to find the code to read from the file within the same class

```
public class CreateAndCopy {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File obj2 = new File("abc.txt");
    Scanner obj1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    PrintWriter testing = new PrintWriter(obj2);
    int x = obj1.nextInt();
    int y = obj1.nextInt();
    int z = obj1.nextInt();
    testing.println(x);
    testing.println(y);
    testing.println(z);
    testing.close();
    System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

reads from the file we created in the class.

Answer (score 1):

To read contents of the file, you can simply use the [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and then iterate over every line and print:

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(obj2));

    String st;
    while ((st = br.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(st);
```

But really, you shouldn't just write everything in your main method - using methods is much cleaner and clearer. I've refactored your code, see for example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File obj2 = createFile();
        writeToFile(obj2);
        System.out.println("");
        readFromFile(obj2);
    }

    private static void readFromFile(File obj2) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(obj2));

        String st;
        while ((st = br.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(st);
    }

    private static void writeToFile(File obj2) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner obj1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        PrintWriter testing = new PrintWriter(obj2);
        int x = obj1.nextInt();
        int y = obj1.nextInt();
        int z = obj1.nextInt();
        testing.println(x);
        testing.println(y);
        testing.println(z);
        testing.close();
    }

    private static File createFile() {
        return new File("abc.txt");
    }
}
```